# Как вызвать success callback

Tags: javascript

Я пишу метод `save` обьекта `user` который должен иметь в себе ивенты success и error (это ивенты?)

```
getCurrentUserDbEntry().then((user) =>{
    // user.set("test1", "xx");
    user.save(null, {
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("successfully");
            deferred.resolve(true);                                                                       
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Внутри метода `getCurrentUserDbEntry` пишу этот метод save:

```
    user.save = function(firstArgument, result){
        //тут вызывается асинхронный запрос и как только я получаю ответ от сервера 
        //мне нужно вернуть success или error,
        // так что бы попасть в функцию из первого примера кода
        // как это сделать ? 
    }
```

Я попробовал `result.success = "OK"`, но это не дало результата.
Все действо выполняется в мобильном приложении написаном с помощью Cordova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result.success(передать сюда то, что является результатом запроса);
```

Comment: да, это оно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Просто используйте Promise и тут тоже:

```
user.save = function(){ // или User.prototype.save?
   return new Promise((success, error) => {
    //тут вызывается асинхронный запрос и как только я получаю ответ от сервера 
    // и success/error также доступны         
   });
}

getCurrentUserDbEntry()
  .then(user => user.save())
  .then(() => console.log('User saved'))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```